# Поиск импортов, методов функций и.т.д из бинарного файла

Tags: c#

Можно ли средствами шарпа сделать поиск функций, методов, стринговых переменных, импорты `.dll` и.т.п из файла, читаю файл и делаю поиск

Comment: Это делается с помощью [Рефлексии](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). И там смотрите по ссылкам.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, может речь про нативную dll?

Comment: @Grundy - может. Ждём уточнения от автора.

Comment: @Grundy, да, native и net.  Я долго думал сначала, потом вроде нашёл что искал через dnlib библиотеку ( но она только для файлом на базе .Net Framework), а нужно ещё нативные...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ^^^